# How to launch a view controller over another view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a quiz app that asks questions in triviaviewcontroller, after 10 questions it segues to the videoviewcontroller, plays the video then segues back to the triviaviewcontroller. The problem is that it restarts the questions from the start, not question 11. Do I need to launch the video from the triviaviewcontroller or what approach do I need to change?

```
@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if noWhitespaceUserAnswer == answers[currentQuestionIndex]
        {
            self.currentQuestionTimerLabel.text = ""

            answerField.text = ""
            currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex + 1 < questions.count ? currentQuestionIndex + 1 : 0
            if (currentQuestionIndex == 4){
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "videoview", sender: self)
                                }
            nextQuestionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]


            animateLabelTransitions()

        }
        else {
            incorrectAnswerHoldLabel.isHidden = false
            submitbuttonwronganswer.isHidden = true
            let time = DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds:UInt64(0.1) ) + Double(4 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) {
                self.submitbuttonwronganswer.isHidden = false
                self.incorrectAnswerHoldLabel.isHidden = true
            }

            answerField.text = ""

        }
    }
```

Here is my videoviewcontroller.

```
 class VideoViewController:  AVPlayerViewController,      AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
fileprivate var firstAppear = true

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if firstAppear {
        do {
            try playVideo()

            firstAppear = false
        } catch AppError.invalidResource(let name, let type) {
            debugPrint("Could not find resource \(name).\(type)")
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Generic error")
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func playVideo() throws {

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "RossCliffJumping", ofType:"m4v") else {
        throw AppError.invalidResource("RossCliffJumping", "m4v")
    }
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(VideoViewController.itemDidFinishPlaying(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
    self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()

    }

}
func itemDidFinishPlaying(_ notification:Notification) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "videofinished", sender: self)
    print("finished")
  }
  deinit{
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
  }

}
    enum AppError : Error { case invalidResource(String, String)
}
```

Comment: You should add your code for more detail. And this is kind of very basic so you can find answer of this easily everywhere.

Comment: I added my code and please directed me to the basic place where I can find this answer everywhere so I don't have to bother you. I'm sorry I have not mastered this. I just need some direction. thank you @ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already launching another view controller. From the sound of your question, it seems you want to call `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` instead of performing another segue, to get back to the first controller. By calling `performSegue` you are creating a new controller, which of course is going to go back to question 1.